# Airflow mandatory task execution Trigger Rule for BranchPythonOperator

Tags: triggers, airflow

I have to create Airflow DAG with these states:
Task1 which is a BranchPythonOperator which decides to execute either Task2 or not and then execute Task3 irrespective of Task2 is ignored or failed or passed meaning Task3 is to be executed in any case. I have introduced a dummy task TaskD to move to Task3 in case the branch condition is not met and Task2 is not executed.

I have set the dependencies as below:

```
Task1.set_downstream(Task2)
Task1.set_downstream(TaskD)
Task2.set_downstream(Task3)
TaskD.set_downstream(Task3)
```

The problem is what to set the trigger_rule for Task3? If I set it to "all_done", would it require to execute both Task2 and TaskD or one can be skipped? If it can work with skipped task then I think I can use "all_done". Also, I can't set it to "one_success" or "one_failed" as I want to execute Task3 no matter if the parent fails or succeeds. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: is it important the task3 will run only after task2 or taskd ?

Comment: yes, Task3 has to run in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So setting the trigger rule to "all_done" for task3 is the way to achieve this.